# How can I set minimumFontSize or lines on a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView`, which I populate with strings. These strings can be short to quite long. If they are quite long I would like to wrap them in 2 lines (or make the text smaller), but they always cut off with 3 dots.

I have tried using `pickerView(_:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:)`, and returning a `UILabel` where I set both `minimumFontSize` and `lines`, but it still cuts off the text with 3 dots.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UILabel` set `minimumScaleFactor` and also set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `YES`.

Comment: This does not work, it still cuts off the text without resizing the font.